# Leer valores dentro de un JSON con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas

Tengo un JSON con el siguiente formato:

```
{"name":{"0":"Primer valor","1":"Segundo valor","2":"Tercer valor", . . ."271":"Ultimo Valor}}
```

Y cuando lo intento imprimir en pantalla, lo que me sale es lo siguiente

```
1
2
3
...
271
```

Lo estoy leyendo de la siguiente manera:

```
f = open("hero_names.json")

data = json.load(f)

for key in data["name"]:
    print(key)
```

Este JSON lo he obtenido con Pandas, a lo mejor he formulado mal el JSON a la hora de guardarlo con Pandas.
Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Prueba con `for value in data["name"].values():` y así puedes imprimir los valores.

Comment: O si quieres seguir usando la estructura `for` actual, entonces cambia el `print` de la siguiente forma: `print(data["name"][key])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Si lo que esperas es obtener los pares de llave y valor entonces debes utilizar `items()`.

**Nota:** En tu pregunta hace falta un `"` después de `Ultimo valor`, no sé si fue un error al redactar la pregunta o si así está tu `dataframe` pero si así está, te enviará el siguiente error:

> Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 75 (char 74)

Ejemplo usando `items()`:

```
import json

# Simulando tu json
f = '{"name":{"0":"Primer valor","1":"Segundo valor","2":"Tercer valor", "271":"Ultimo Valor"}}'

data = json.loads(f)

# Utilizamos items para obtener llave y valor
for key, value in data["name"].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Esto imprime:

```
0 Primer valor
1 Segundo valor
2 Tercer valor
271 Ultimo Valor
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.
Respecto al fallo de "Ultimo valor", si, error de redacción.
Se me olvidó decirlo, pero lo que quería sacar es "Primer valor", "Segundo valor" etc, pero con tu respuesta ya puedo hacerlo